# Windows Azure blob zip and send to client (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, zip, azure-blob-storage

I have some files stored in Windows Azure blob container (let's say file1.txt and file2.txt).
In an ASP.NET MVC4 application (hosted on azurewebsites) I need to create a "download as zip" link. When user clicks it, he gets a zip file containing both txt files.
I'm having hard time writing controller method for accomplishing this task :-(  Can someone please provide short example?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here goes some code. Code is in raw format, please enhance it as per your usage.
I used DotNetZip and Table Storage Nugets.

Code to generate Zip -

```
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BlobRepository rep = new BlobRepository();

        // Download files from Blob storage
        byte[] b = rep.DownloadFileFromBlob(filename);

        zip.AddEntry("sample1", b);
        //add as many files as you want

        zip.Save(stream);
        // use that stream for your usage.
    }
```

Code for download blob -

```
public byte[] DownloadFileFromBlob(string filename)
{
    // Get Blob Container 
    CloudBlobContainer container = BlobUtilities.GetBlobClient.GetContainerReference(BlobUtilities.FileContainer);
    // Get reference to blob (binary content) 
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
    // Read content 
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        blockBlob.DownloadToStream(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Blob utilities helper class -

```
internal class BlobUtilities
{
    public static CloudBlobClient GetBlobClient
    {
        get
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string here");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            return blobClient;
        }
    }
    public static string FileContainer
    {
        get
        {
            return "container name here";
        }
    }
}
```